# how to change the color of cross button in ui-select module of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select for multiple selection in drop down.When an item is selected it shows the cross button on the right upar of selected item. Can I change the color of cross button to red ?

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleUserDemo.selectedUserWithGroupBy" theme="bootstrap" ng-change="refreshUsers($select.search) : '')" style="width:100%;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="--Select--">
       <span ng-bind = "$item.userName"></span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="user in Users track by $index" refresh="refreshUsers($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
       <div ng-bind-html="user.userName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
           <small>
             Email Id: <span ng-bind-html="user.email | highlight: $select.search"></span>
           </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: here is the link of plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0?p=preview

Comment: So you're talking about the button's on the chips / results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Chrome's Developer Tools (F12) you can inspect single elements by pressing Ctrl+Shift+C and clicking the element afterwards. This way I found out that the class of the "cross buttons" is `close ui-select-match-close`.

Chrome outputs the computed styles:

[image: Computed styles for cross]

There you can see, that the span has its *color*-attribute set to **#000000** and its *opacity*-attribute set to **0.2**.With this information you're able to style the buttons with the following CSS:

```
.close.ui-select-match-close {
    color:#f00;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Other browsers do have great Developer Tools, too.